# mysql cannot work for the search

Tags: php, mysql

i am new here. I self-learnt a lot of things, but today, i really stucked with this issue i have to post a question here. It is as follows:

I was changing a droplist selection to a checkbox format in one of the filter of my search engine. I can't share the link of my page because it requires an administrative password which i can't share. Below are the codes, which i tried working on.

The search is working only if you check one checkbox. If you search with two or more checkboxes checked, the search results will only show the category which consist the most results. Meaning... if i have three categories, tutors, mentors and teachers. And in my database there are 1000 tutors, 500 mentors and 200 teachers. A search with the mentors and teachers checkboxes checked will spawn a result of that 500 mentors only.

What i want is the search results to be combined, instead of showing only 500 mentors as the search results, it should be showing a total of 700 (inclusive 500 mentors and 200 teachers).

I have also tried adding `[]` behind like this `name='Category[]'`

The search worked but every combination of checked checkbox(s) i search will always end up with the 1000 tutors as the results. Hence, adding the [] made things even worse.

Codes as follow:

HTML:

```
<div style="font-family:arial;font-size:15px;margin:8px 15px 0px 15px;">
    <b>Select a tutor category</b>

    <?php
        $strSQL = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM CATEGORY";
        if ($pDBAgent->Query($strSQL) == false)
        {
            echo $pDBAgent->GetLastError();
            exit;
        }
        $iCount = $pDBAgent->GetCount();
        for ($i=0; $i<$iCount; $i++)
        {
            $strID = $pDBAgent->GetResult($i, 'ID');
            $strName = $pDBAgent->GetResult($i, 'NAME');
            echo "<div style='margin:0px 5px;font-family:arial;font-size:13px;display:inline-block'><input type='checkbox' name='Category' value='$strID'>$strName</div>";
        }
    ?> 
</div>
```

PHP:

```
if ($iCategory != 0)
{
    //Special search for full time tutor
    if (($iCategory == 2) || ($iCategory == 5) || ($iCategory == 8))
    {
        $iCategoryFullTime = $iCategory + 1;
        $strCondition .= " AND (CATEGORY_ID = $iCategory OR CATEGORY_ID = $iCategoryFullTime)";
    }
    else
        $strCondition .= " AND CATEGORY_ID = $iCategory";
}
```

Comment: The code is not relevant to Your problem.

Comment: Where is the code that handles the filtering?

Comment: see above i added some more information, which i think may be relevant.